# How to make Barplot with R

Tags: r, plot

I tried to make a barplot with R and I used my dataset named cmtn but that does not work. This is the dataset that I used:
    [image: dataset]

And this is the code:

```
x <- c(42012.8,36328.2,546.9,109.4,7123.3,80865.5,11133.3,1325.4,9214.5,9290.3)

names(x)=c("Importation","Exportation","Formation brute de capital","Impots 
sur production","valeur ajoutees ", "PIB","Production_secteur","Salaires"    
,"Credits","valeur_produits")

barplot(x,space = c(1.5), axisnames = FALSE,col = 
c("indianred","indianred1","indianred2","indianred3","salmon",
"salmon1","salmon ","salmon3","seagreen3","seagreen4"),main = "Commerce", 
font.main = 1)
```

Comment: Please provide your data frame with reproducible codes, not with a picture. You may use `dump` to output the data frame into code texts.

Comment: When I run your code,  I get a barplot.  What is not working about it?

Comment: @ytu: `dput()` is usually more handy if you're only dealing with a single object of reasonable size.

Comment: thank's it works now

Comment: @AkselA Hmm I thought `dump` is always better because the document of `dput` reads "_This is **not** a good way to transfer objects between R sessions. 'dump' is better..._"

Comment: @ytu: Both `dput()` and `dump()` has limitations in that they represent everything as plaintext. `dump()` has some extra trickery, but will also ultimately fail with more complicated objects, like S4 and environments. The safe way to share your work is to use `save()`, but if all you want to do is distribute something like a single list object with attributes and types intact, `dput()` and `dump()` will work the same, except that `dput()` will write to console, making it more amenable copy/paste action.